# Where is the flaw in my logic that is causing an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers

I'm trying out "code golf" type problems to prepare for interviews. At the moment I'm trying to do the one where you move the odd elements of an array to the back (without necessarily preserving the order). I've looked over my logic many times and can't think of any case that could cause an infinite loop. However, I'm getting a `Timeout` when I try to run it. I've commented out my thought process for you to see.

```
#include <iostream>

void int_swap (int *pi1, int *pi2)
{
    int temp = *pi1;
    *pi1 = *pi2; 
    *pi2 = temp;
}

void odds_to_back (int *arr, size_t n)
{
    int * end = arr + n; // get pointer to 1 off the end of the array
    if (arr == end) return; // handle case of empty array
    --end; // move pointer to last element of the array
    while (arr != end) 
    {
       if (*arr % 2) // if first pointer is odd
       {
           if (!(*end % 2)) // if second pointer is even
           {
              int_swap(arr, end); // swap first and second
              ++arr; // increment first
           }
           else // second pointer is odd
           {
              while ((*end % 2) && arr != end) --end; // move second pointer towards first until second pointer is even or hits the first
           }
       }
       else // if first is even
       {
          ++arr; // increment first
       }
    }      

}

int main ( )
{
   int myArray [] = {1, 3, 5, 6, 19, 1, 2, 2};
   size_t N = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int);
   odds_to_back(myArray, N);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) std::cout << myArray[i] << " ";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Patryk Zglenicki Your edit solves not only the typo but also the question.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that is a hard one. You are calling `swap (arr, end)` and not your own `int_swap`. So, at least with my [test code](http://ideone.com/JDKipV) the function [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) which is changing the pointers (and not the values pointed to) is called.

Changing the call to your `int_swap` [looks promising](http://ideone.com/4huhdG).